# Cannot stop intersection on money as particle system

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I'm making a simulation of a load of money flowing and piling up.

I have a plane that they're sat on and another plane they're running into on the left, both with high friction to stop them and make them pile up.

The problem I'm having is that they "notes" are clipping through each other and intersecting.

[image: Intersecting particle system]

I am using a particle emitter, and using a flattened cube with the money texture on for the "render as" object. The money mesh has collision and rigid body set on it.

Here are the settings for the money mesh that comes out of the emitter:
[image]

Here are the settings for the emitter:

[image]

As with every time I post on here, I feel like I've exausted Google at this point and come to a dead end. I thought "size deflect" was going to be my saviour but alas, no cigar.

The money mesh is scaled to 20x and the scale on the emitter is 0.05. This is the only way "size deflect" would enable without my money being positioned up in the air amove the emitter.

I have tried setting collision to mesh on the money object, to try and give it a better resolution for collision.

I have set the physics integration to RK4 as I read this gives the most realism.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: hello, I don't think that physics work for particles if this is what you're trying to do

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Thank you for responding.

Comment: would it work if you used a pile of objects with rigid body instead of a particle system?

Comment: Thanks, I will give that method a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles do not take the physical shape of the instanced object into account. They are just points, so usually the interaction with collision objects is at the center of the point/sphere shown in the *3D Viewport*, no matter how large the point will be shown.

The term *Size Deflect* is in another way misleading - apart from not taking the size of the instanced object into account, it actually refers to the *Scale* you find in the particle system settings under *Render*.

If the *Scale* for example is set to 0.1, *Size Deflect* will - instead of using the particle center for collisions - use a sphere with a radius of 0.1 as collision shape.

The *Size* which is set under *Viewport Display* however is only the size showing in the viewport, it will not have any effect on the collision shape used by *Size Deflect*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You seem very knowledgable. Could I ask how you'd go about doing this please, which would take the shape collisions into account?

Comment: Simply, I don't do it with particles. You would have to do a physics simulation with _Rigid Bodies_, but depending on the amount of objects this can be quite heavy for your computer. To make it a bit easier, instead of regular duplicating the notes object with Shift+D, you should make linked duplicates with Alt+D so that they all use the same object data.

Comment: Thanks for that. Based on what you've said I've just found a video that shows converting emitted objects into "physical" objects which you can then simulate. I will start there. Thank you.

Comment: @Casualbob Yes, there are ways of converting them, but depending on how you get the notes into the scene and where and when intersections happen I'm not sure if it is useful to start with emitting particles while you could also start directly with rigid bodies. But as I said, dpeends on your scene etc.